# Insert a node at a specific place in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

I'd like to insert a node into a specific place.

Each day, I log in, expand the following nodes: "Engineering worklog" > "2019" > "Q2" > "week 20" > "05/20/15".

I'd love to have a single command to insert all of that at the correct place in my org file, but I can find precious little about inserting nodes into a large org-mode file.

Anyone have something like this or pointers for me?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [`datetree`](https://gitlab.com/jagrg/datetree) package I wrote for the purpose of answering your question. With datetree.el in your `load-path` add the following lines to your .emacs/init.el file:

```
(require 'datetree)
(setq datetree-root "Engineering worklog"
      datetree-format-string '("%Y" "Q%q" "week %W" "%D"))
```

Now open the Org file and call `datetree-find`, which should either jump the current entry or create a new one at the appropriate location. By default entries are placed chronologically with the newest entry at the bottom. If that's not the case for you, you'll have to change `datetree-order-reversed-p` to `t`.

What datetree does is it jumps to the first node and moves down sequentially until a subchild matching the current date is found. If a subchild is not found, jump to the matching child and insert a new sibling. Likewise, if a child is not found, jump to the parent node and so on.